# Php title regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace a title tag from `|title|Page title|` to `<title>Page Title</title>`, using this regular expression. But being a complete amateur, it's not gone to well..

```
'^|title|^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}|$' => '<title>$1</title>'
```

I would love to know how to fix it, and more importantly, what I did wrong and why it was wrong.

Comment: Your character group doesn't contain a space?

Comment: You could just `explode('|', $string)`

Comment: Does not work without the space either, I acctually used "test" on my accual webserver, and it didn't swallow that either. I keep getting this error spit in my face:

        Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: No ending matching delimiter '>' found in D:\www\core\classes\system.class.php on line 37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it:

- You should escape the | characters as they have special meaning in a
  regex and you are using it as a plain character.
- You should add the space character to your search group

  ```
  $string = '|title|Page title|';
  $pattern = '/\|title\|([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]{1,})\|/';
  $replacement = '<title>$1</title>';
  echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string); //echoes <title>Page title</title>
  ```

See working [**demo**](http://codepad.org/jkB2HLAH)

OP posted some code in comments which is wrong, try this version:

```
$regular_expressions = array( array( '/\|title\|([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]{1,})\|/' , '<title>$1</title>' )); 
foreach($regular_expressions as $regexp){
   $data = preg_replace($regexp[0], $regexp[1], $data); 
}
```

Comment: That works, right up until I try to insert it into my system class like this:

            public function render_template_basic($data){
  $data = trim($data);
  $regular_expressions = array(
   '/\|title\|([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]{1,})\|/' => '<title>$1</title>',
  );
  foreach($regular_expressions as $regexp){
   $data = preg_replace($regexp[0], $regexp[1], $data);
  }
  return $data;
 }

Then I get a "Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in D:\www\core\classes\system.class.php on line 36" error

Comment: Sorry for double post. Cannot edit my previous comment it appears.

When I print $regexp[0] it prints out "<" and when I print $regexp[1] it prints "t", what on earth is going on here?!

I've never come across a issue of this nature, it's so strange because something happens which isn't called upon!

Answer (score 0):

Heres a little function I came up with a while back to essentially scrape the titles of a page when users submitted links through my service. What this function does is will get the contents of a provided URL. Seek a title tag, if found, get whats between the title tag and dump it's result. With a little tweaking I am sure you can use a replace method for whatever your doing, and make it work for your needs. So this is more of a starting point rather than an answer but overall I hope it helps to some extent.

```
$url = 'http://www.chrishacia.com';
function get_page_title($url){

    if( !($data = file_get_contents($url)) ) return false;
    if( preg_match("#<title>(.+)<\/title>#iU", $data, $t))  {
        return trim($t[1]);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
var_dump(get_page_title($url));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $s = "|title|Page title|";

    $s = preg_replace('/^\|title\|([^\|]+)\|/', "<title>$1</title>", $s);

    echo $s;
?>
```